# (VBA) Boolean conditions in IF = TRUE; skips guts despite of this

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

I've got the following IF-conditions set up:

```
    If Range("D" & x) + Range("D" & z) = 0 = True And (Range("G" & x) = Range("G" & z)) = True And (IsEmpty(Range("A" & x)) = False) = True And (IsEmpty(Range("C" & x)) = False) = True Then

          [guts]

    End if
```

I've inserted all of the **(condition) = True** in order to be able to evaluate each individual condition while debugging, and ALL of them return TRUE = TRUE. And yet it doesn't execute the guts of the boolean. It just doesn't make sense to me, but hopefully one of you can see what is wrong with it. I created a test sheet to run the macro on, containing only a few rows of data that I know should return TRUE on all of the conditions, but it doesn't work. I have a feeling that it is a painfully obvious error.

You can download a sample including some data here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?rm299bttfsp1v01

Comment: if you can upload sample data - just do it - it always helps ;)

Comment: Alright! I'll have it up in a minute.

Comment: can it be that `Range("C"` is wrong? because in your file, this column is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatted this and made a pastable example of it:

```
 Public Sub demo()
  Dim x, Z As Long

  x = 1
  Z = 1

  If Range("D" & x) + Range("D" & Z) = 0 = True And _
  (Range("G" & x) = Range("G" & Z)) = True And _
  (IsEmpty(Range("A" & x)) = False) = True And _
  (IsEmpty(Range("C" & x)) = False) = True Then

          Debug.Print "[guts]"

    End If

End Sub
```

It works for me, if A1=12 and C1=12 (e.g.)

But this is how I would write this:

```
Public Sub demo()
  Dim x, Z As Long

  x = 1
  Z = 1

  'to confirm
  Debug.Print Range("D" & x) + Range("D" & Z) = 0
  Debug.Print Range("G" & x) = Range("G" & Z)
  Debug.Print Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & x))
  Debug.Print Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & x))

  If Range("D" & x) + Range("D" & Z) = 0 And _
     Range("G" & x) = Range("G" & Z) And _
     Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & x)) And _
     Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & x)) Then

          Debug.Print "[guts]"
  End If

End Sub
```

*Edit*

You can test this easily, using this code:

```
  Debug.Print Range("D" & x) + Range("D" & Z) = 0 And _
              Range("G" & x) = Range("G" & Z) And _
              Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & x)) And _
              Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & x))
```

Paste if after  `For Z = 8 To 16`.

It does not resolve to true, that is why you are not getting the guts ;)

Comment: Oh, neat. I did not know you could format the conditions like that.
But it still doesn't work. I would appreciate it very much if you could try to take a look at the sample I uploaded.

Comment: looked at it - your condition just does not resolve true - see my edit.

Comment: Oh dear. Thanks to you I found the error. Earlier today I made a change with regards to what columns contain the data, and I forgot to correct the column letter in the last condition. I knew it was a stupid mistake. Looking at the same stuff for hours makes you blind to the little details, I guess.

Thank you!

Comment: @KHH - this is why you should think about using named-ranges or constants for your column-references - helps a lot, especially if the macros are growing big. happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are getting hung up by the order of operations? It looks like you may be missing a set of parenthesis around the first condition...

```
If (Range("D" & x) + Range("D" & z) = 0) = True And (Range("G" & x) = Range("G" & z)) = True And (IsEmpty(Range("A" & x)) = False) = True And (IsEmpty(Range("C" & x)) = False) = True Then

      [guts]

End if
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work. Could you please take a look at the sample I uploaded? I appreciate your help.